# How to set pgpassword and run postgres command in one line using Python?

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm trying to set pgpassword and run pg command in one line but not working,

I'm using Windows.

```
os.system('SET PGPASSWORD=admin && psql -U postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE TEST"')
```

what I got:

> psql: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"

It's weird because it's the password

How can I solve this?

**EDIT:**

SOLVED

```
cmd1 = 'SET PGPASSWORD=admin'
cmd2 = 'psql -U postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE TEST"'
os.system(cmd1 + '&&' + cmd2)
```

Comment: Don't use `psql` from inside Python; use a library like `psycopg2`.

Comment: `subprocess` has been preferred over `os.system()` since 2.4; there's [a section on how to do the replacement in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements). If you've got an answer then can you answer the question rather than adding the answer to the question?

Comment: What is the difference in the solution? Is not having spaces around '&& the solution? Or is there any other difference?